# bloqueo de botón con condición del tiempo androidstudio

Tags: android-studio

me pueden ayudar, en un activity tengo dos botones y un temporizador al presionar el botón el temporizador inicia. Lo que busco es la manera de dar un condicionamiento a ese botón que no inicie el temporizador si le compara con la hora y a partir de cierta hora funcione. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido al sito!!! te doy la bienvenida y te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. Es importante modifiques el formato de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

define tus fechas

```
f_fecha_after 
f_fecha_before
f_fecha_autorizado



if(f_fecha_autorizado.after(f_fecha_after ) && f_fecha_autorizado.before(f_fecha_before)) {
    // si tu f_fecha_autorizado esta en el rango de estas otras fechas.. 
    //  realiza la acccion 
}
else
{
    //no hace nada
}
```